# How to show select option dependent on another select option in Flask (Python)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I am creating a lead form using *Flask (Python)* where users can register **Leads**.  I have two Fields both are coming from Database, 1st is **Category** (Parent) and 2nd is **Products** (Child).

Products field should be dependent on Category.

[Product Select Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKKkv.png)

code in template:

```
<label>Product Category</label>
<select class="form-control" name="product_category">            
    <option value=""></option>{% for r in catagory_name %}
    <option value="{{ r.catagory_name }}">{{ r.catagory_name }}</option>{% endfor %}
</select>


<label>Product</label>
<select class="form-control" name="product">            
    <option value=""></option>{% for r in product_name %}
    <option value="{{ r.product_name }}">{{ r.product_name }}</option>{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Now What I want that when user will click on Category, only the products which are of that selected category should be shown and rest should be hidden without refreshing the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first get the id of the parent data. then query the child datas. you can use an ajax get request for that. then iterate each items on the drop down.

heres an example

```js
JQUERY:

$(#PARENT).on('click', function(){
 var parent= $('#PARENT').find('option:selected').text();

 $.getJSON({ type: "GET",   
     url: "<?php echo base_url('url to query the product of category')?>",   
     async: false,
     data: { name:parent },
     dataType: 'json',
     success : function(data)
     {   
         var child = $('#CHILD')
         parent_child = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         child.html('');
         $.each(parent_child, function(key,value) {
             if(value.isActive == 1){
                 var child_option = $('<li><a class="gear-category" data-key="'+value.gearID+'" href="javascript:void(0)">'+value.gearName+'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>');
                 child_option.data('index', key);
                 child.append(child_option);

             }
         });
     },
     error: function(e)
     {
     console.log(e);
     }

 }); 
});
```

```html
HTML :


    <label>Product Category</label>
<select ID="PARENT" class="form-control" name="product_category">            
    <option value=""></option>{% for r in catagory_name %}
    <option value="{{ r.catagory_name }}">{{ r.catagory_name }}</option>{% endfor %}
</select>


<label>Product</label>
<select ID="CHILD" class="form-control" name="product">            
    <option value=""></option>{% for r in product_name %}
    <option value="{{ r.product_name }}">{{ r.product_name }}</option>{% endfor %}
</select>
```

PS: sorry if the answer was unclear. Im new to stackoverflow

Comment: I'm unable to get your answer. Can you please explain with my code?